# Configuring a C&C for a RAT

Tags: malware, dynamic-analysis, development

Where would I start when needing to configure a command and control server for a RAT?

So that my dynamic analysis can be more complete.

Note: I have been to the topics section of this stack exchange. "tools commonly used for reverse engineering hardware or software", this post would comply with that particular topic. It is definitely answerable, and not broad. 
Also, this question is relevant (in compliance with the relevance guidelines) as many people on this exchange are new to malware analysis.

Comment: you need to ask specific questions rather than for general advice.

Comment: technically speaking all answers are "general advice", my question was pretty specific. this is a reverse engineering forum. I am asking for additional sources of info, like from a feed someone saw earlier or maybe a sentence or two about what they do. nothing crazy man.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may use FakeNet so that you can simulate the connection specially the IP address and ports.